# Typescript Declaration File doesn't assist autocomplete

Tags: typescript

I have this in a file called `button.tsx`:

```
export default function Button(props, children=[])  {
    // something
};
```

I place `button.d.tsx` next to it:

```
declare module 'button' {
    export default function(props:any, children?:HTMLElement[]): any;
}
```

But Visual Studio Code tells me both props and children are `any` when I start typing:

```
import Button from './button';
Button(
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't want to put type definitions in `button.tsx`. I rather keep it as fairly vanilla ES6.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `.tsx` (or `ts`) file the typescript compiler will take the definitions for the functions from that file, not from the `d.ts`. This makes sense as the compiler could be generating the definitions itself (that is a compiler option).

But since you are writing the component in typescript, why is the extra definition file necessary? You can just add the type annotations directly to the function in your `tsx`:

```
export default function Button(props: any, children:HTMLElement[]=[])  {
    // something
};
```